# missing lines when read csv file into R

Tags: r, csv

I have trouble with reading csv file into R. The file contains more than 10000 lines, but only 4977 lines are read into R. And there is no missing value in the file. My code below:

```
mydata = read.csv("12260101.csv", quote = "\"", skipNul = TRUE)
write.csv(mydata, "check.csv")
```

Comment: My suspicion is that part of your CSV file is malformed, e.g. an extra column, a missing quote, etc.  Could you try opening the file in Excel?  This might quickly reveal where the problem(s) is, so that you can correct the file.

Comment: try `readr::read_csv()` as @ed_sans suggested. Since you have `skipNul` in your parameters, this file already sounds like it's malformed. You'll get better diagnostics with other CSV reading functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the CSV file. You might want to compare rows that aren't being imported with the imported ones. 
I would try using the function `read_csv()` from the package `readr` or `fread()` from `data.table`.

Answer (score -1):

As other posters pointed out, hard to reproduce without an example. I had a similar issue with `read.csv` but `fread` worked without any problems. Might be worth a shot to give it a try.